# Wordpress: isHome function

Tags: php, wordpress

is there any native function in wordpress to check if the page is home page?

because i want to make some script like this

```
if (isHome){
    include 'somescript.php';
}
```

PS:
i use wordpress 3.0.1

thanks,

GusDe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `is_home()`
change it to

```
if (is_home()){
    include 'somescript.php';
}
```

Comment: soo it's mean my question is nearly the answer, sorry for such dumb question. because im new using wordpress @_@

Answer (score 4):

There is a `is_home()` function, but you *may* need to use `is_front_page()` instead.

See [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) for details on page-identifying functions.

Comment: yes you right, in the first i try use is_home, but for more dinamically which is setting from the front page i add `if (is_home() || if_front_page()`